# bootstrap modal not working when i try to edit one record in firefox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a form in modal bootstrap where I edit a record. Works fine in chrome browser, but not working in firefox. What happens is that submit does not work in Firefox. Some idea about the problem? Look below parts of the code.

layouts/application.html.erb

```
(...)

<div class="content">
    <%= yield %>
</div>

(...)
```

photos/index.erb

```
<h1>Painting Gallery</h1>

<div id="photos">
  <%= render @photos %>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>

<% if can? :create, @horse.photos.build %>
    <%= form_for([@farm,@horse, @photo], :html => {:multipart => true} ) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :image, "Upload paintings:" %>
        <%= f.file_field :image, multiple: true, name: "photo[image]" %>
        <%= f.submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

_photo.erb

```
<%= link_to t("photo.edit"), edit_farm_horse_photo_path(@farm.slug,@horse.slug,photo.id), :remote => true, :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#editPhoto"} %>
```

_form.erb

```
<div id="editPhoto" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPhotoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="editPhotoLabel">Editar foto</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <%= form_for([@farm,@horse, @photo], :html => { :id => "frmPhoto"},:remote => true) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :name %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>
      <p>
        <%= f.file_field :image %>
      </p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <%= f.submit "Salvar" , :id => "btnEnviar" ,:class => "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>
     <% end %>
</div>
```

edit.js.erb

```
$(".content").append('<%= escape_javascript(render("photos/form")) %>');
$("#editPhoto").modal("show");
```

photos_controller.rb

```
  def edit
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      @photo = @horse.photos.find(params[:id])
      if @photo.update_attributes(params[:photo])
        format.js
      else
        render :edit
      end
    end
  end
```

after clicking the edit link the modal appears but when i click on submit button nothing happens. Look the browser response when i click the edit link.

```
$(".content").append('<div id=\"editPhoto\" class=\"modal hide fade\" tabindex=\"-1\" role=\"dialog\" aria-labelledby=\"editPhotoLabel\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\n  <div class=\"modal-header\">\n    <button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">×<\/button>\n    <h3 id=\"editPhotoLabel\">Editar foto<\/h3>\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"modal-body\">\n    <form accept-charset=\"UTF-8\" action=\"/criatorio-sagitario/horses/teste--2/photos/9\" class=\"edit_photo\" data-remote=\"true\" enctype=\"multipart/form-data\" id=\"frmPhoto\" method=\"post\"><div style=\"margin:0;padding:0;display:inline\"><input name=\"utf8\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"&#x2713;\" /><input name=\"_method\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"put\" /><input name=\"authenticity_token\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"jNz2kSH0KXGchNKglmN66Vdd/gyMxyyc9jTT5bf50/w=\" /><\/div>\n      <div class=\"field\">\n        <label for=\"photo_name\">Name<\/label><br />\n        <input id=\"photo_name\" name=\"photo[name]\" size=\"30\" type=\"text\" value=\"Original\" />\n      <\/div>\n      <p>\n        <input id=\"photo_image\" name=\"photo[image]\" type=\"file\" />\n      <\/p>\n  <\/div>\n  <div class=\"modal-footer\">\n    <button class=\"btn\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-hidden=\"true\">Close<\/button>\n    <input class=\"btn btn-primary\" id=\"btnEnviar\" name=\"commit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Salvar\" />\n  <\/div>\n<\/form><\/div>\n\n\n');

$("#editPhoto").modal("show");
```

Comment: What do your browser and server console say?

Comment: Hello, @juanpastas . Both say nothing. Is like i didn't clicked on button.

Comment: I don't see where you are rendering `_photo`, neither where you have `.content` element

Comment: @juanpastas, edited. Look the new code.

Comment: after clicking the link, nothing in browser console related to AJAX requests, right?

Comment: Exactly. But only in firefox. In chrome browser the request happens ok

Comment: @juanpastas, just to confirm understanding, the modal appears on the page, the problem is when i click on the submit button.

Comment: I could not :p. Is weird you don't have any error message, those are very difficult problems to solve

Comment: i think the problem is on the appended html. Probably contains any thing where firefox does not understand. But i don't what. =(

Comment: Maybe you have an unclosed tag, possible?

Comment: Aparently not. But i'll test some things in html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I don't know why but "f.submit" don't worked. I submited in jquery and worked

edit.js.erb

```
$(".content").append('<%= escape_javascript(render("photos/form"))  %>');

$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {
$("#frmPhoto").submit();
});

$("#editPhoto").modal("show");
```